# If $f(x)$ is an integrable function in $[a,b],$ then the set where the function is continuous, is dense in $[a,b]$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, riemann-integration

True or false: if $f$ is an integrable function on $[a,b]$, then the set where the function is continuous, is dense in $[a,b]$.

Observation: the function $f$ is Riemann-integrable.

Comment: You need to explain what you have tried so far and the context (for example, is that a homework or what leads you to this).

Answer (score -1):

**Hint:** Use Lebesgue's integrability condition. Notice that a subset of $[a,b]$ which is almost equal to it (its Lebesgue measure is $b-a$) is dense in it.

Comment: Thank you, I liked Steins; gate

Comment: You're welcome :) Me too ;)